# Azure Mobile Services returns MobileServicePushFailedException after calling PullAsync()

Tags: azure, xamarin.android

I have created a Xamarin.Android application that uses Azure Mobile Services.  I am receiving a `MobileServicePushFailedException` after calling `PullAsync()`.

After inspecting the exception, I see that my client is trying to send Update operations instead of Insert operations for new rows created on the client that do not yet exist on the server.  The server sees an update come through for a non-existent row and returns a 404 error.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/255#issuecomment-261355317).

Comment: Try to use SyncAsync code in a try/catch block, catching a MobileServicePushFailedException. You'll be able to inspect the exception details either by having a breakpoint in your catch block or by writing the results to the output/trace.
In the exception, you can check the detailed information about the issue. 
Also, refer to this document: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-ios-handling-conflicts-offline-data.md, which describes "how to synchronize data and handle conflicts when using the offline capabilities of Azure Mobile Services."

Comment: I do that, and I get the exception I noted.  There are several new records which are trying to get updated instead of inserted and I don't know why.